# How to create pseudo code for Braitenberg vehicle 2b?

Tags: sensors, wheeled-robot

I am asked to make Braitenberg vehicle for small robotic exhibition. I am asked to use GL5528 light sensor. My job is to construct and program Braitenberg vehicle 2b, which uses GL5528 light sensors and wheels.

Can anyone please help me with and create pseudo code for Braitenberg vehicle 2b please would be really appreciated as I have wired the robot but am weak at programming part just a general pseudo code would do thank you.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* KarateKing, but I'm afraid that questions asking for code are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given coding problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so please try to include what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask], [about] and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for advice on writing a good question.

Comment: You're asking for pseudo code for a particular type of vehicle, but what exactly should that behavior *be?* Should the robot turn to face light and then stop? Should it keep driving until it registers a particular light intensity? Should it ever reverse? If you can create a flowchart of behavior then that would outline your pseudo code and you could write your implementations from there.